# Modify Magento PayPal PayFlow Pro Response Messages

Tags: magento, paypal, magento-1.7, payflowpro

By default, Magento shows the actual response from PayPal (PayFlow Pro) which isn't always that nice or friendly. For example one of the fraud prevention messages came back as "Declined by Fraud Service". Is there a way I can modify the response that is displayed to give a friendlier response?

What Magento core files do I need to **copy** and then modify to override the default pass-through of Paypal messages?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you looking to code your own solution to this?

Comment: Yes- if you know what template files I should modify, I can make it happen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where the error message is being set (Payflow Link):
https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/4bc632edf76c1008b7dccde3e5c7357ce2c00087/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Payflowlink.php#L282

And for Payflow Pro:
https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/4bc632edf76c1008b7dccde3e5c7357ce2c00087/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Payflowpro.php#L437

Comment: Did the references above assist you in modifying the PayFlow Pro responses?